# What is a practical example of using the suspend command in Bash?

Tags: bash, process-management, job-control

`suspend` is a builtin command in Bash. When would you naturally use this command and find it useful?

Comment: The shell suspends itself everytime it forks a child process, i.e. runs a command where said command is an external program, requiring  a `fork/exec` system call

Comment: In an interactive shell this allows the child process to get control of the terminal, whilst not having the parent shell interacting with the terminal, which gets messy.

Comment: @velour, but that doesn't require running a separate command to that effect?

Comment: @the_velour_fog Technically, the parent shell is not suspended (it doesn't get a `STOP` signal) when it forks a child process. I'm also a bit confused by your second comment.

Comment: @ilkkachu no. say you are at a interactive shell prompt and you run the command `rsync -av foo bar` you are providing the command to the shell, which then forks itself and then execs (replaces) its 2nd image with the `rsync` process. My understanding (and I could be wrong) is that its at this point the shell suspends itself to get out of the childs way. (allow the child exclusive use of the terminal - which both parent and child are connected to)

Comment: @the_velour_fog No, the parent shell waits for the forked process to finish using `wait()` probably. If it was suspended with `STOP`, the child would need to signal it to resume before it exited, and there would be no way for the parent to get the exit status of the child process. The parent _is_ suspended, but not by a `STOP` signal.

Comment: @Kusalananda ok, right `wait()` sounds reasonable to me. I said *The shell suspends itself everytime it forks a child process*. I didn't say anything about receiving any stop signals, that would make no sense.

Comment: At the system programming level, it's important to pay attention to the distinction between being _stopped_ (process state T; the effect of <kbd>^Z</kbd>, SIGSTOP, and `suspend`) and being _sleeping_ (process state S; any blocking system call, such as `wait`).  At the level of user interactions, though, really the only difference is that a stopped process won't proceed until the user takes a specific action (such as `fg`) to make it proceed, whereas a sleeping process will wake back up automatically when some event happens.

Comment: (cont'd) ... so it's not _wrong_ to say that processes in both states are "suspended", but system programmers will get nitpicky at you, and since the 'suspend' shell built-in performs a _stop_, if I were writing documentation aimed at end-users I would equate "suspended" with "stopped" and use some other term, perhaps "waiting", for the other state.

Comment: @the_velour_fog Even ignoring the sleep/stop/suspend distinction, running a command doesn't require the user to explicitly use the builtin `suspend` command. As in your example, the command was `rsync ...`, not `suspend rsync...` or anything like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's say you lack both GNU `screen` and `tmux` (and X11, *and* virtual consoles) but want to switch between a login shell and another interactive shell.

You would first login on the console, and then start a new shell, temporarily blocking the login shell.  To get the login shell back to do some work there, you'd do `suspend`. Then you would `fg` to get the interactive shell back to continue with whatever it was you did there.

In fact, with job control, the login shell could spawn a number of interactive shells as background jobs that you could switch to with `fg %1`, `fg %2` etc., but to get back to the login shell, you would need to use `suspend` unless you wanted to manually `kill -s STOP $$`.

Also note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> at the prompt in an interactive shell won't suspend it.

**EDIT:** I initially had a long hypothetical section about the use of `suspend` in a script, but since the command requires job control and since non-interactive shells usually don't have job control, I deleted that section.

---

Deleted section with `suspend` replaced by `kill -s STOP $$` (this really doesn't belong to the answer any more, but it may be interesting to others anyway):

Let's say you have a background process (a script) in a script, and that this background process at some stage needs to stop and wait for the parent process to tell it to go on. This could be so that the parent has time to extract and move files into place or something like that.

The child script would suspend (`kill -s STOP $$`), and the parent script would send a `CONT` signal to it when it was okay to continue.

It gives you the opportunity to implement a sort of synchronisation between a parent process and a child process (although very basic as the parent shell process more or less needs to guess that the child process is suspended, although this can be fixed by having the child trap `CONT` and not suspend if that signal is received too early).